# jQuery fade / animate opacity to different display type then block

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a few divs I am vertically aligning with `display: table` and `display: table-cell` for the inners. Anyways, the problem is, when I animate the opacity with jQuery either through `fadeTo()` or `fadeIn`, it always add's the `display: block` inlining. How can I keep the display type from changing during and after the opacity animation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never-mind, It looks like I can add `.fadeTo(300, 1.0).css('display', 'table-row')` and this fixes the issue

Comment: Also, you can animate the opacity as well just using .animate ({'opacity' : 1}, 300) so you don't have to call the .css function everytime. Both work though :)